# Is there a public smart contract for ICOs?

Tags: spl-token

I am looking for a smart contract template for my ICO but cannot find any. Do I even need one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find anchor [examples here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/tests). What you're looking for is the [ido pool example](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/ido-pool/programs/ido-pool/src/lib.rs)

Comment: But is there a live contract that I can reuse?

Comment: you can deploy your own with `anchor build` then `anchor deploy`

Comment: this is inefficient